# Parsing JSON string/object in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I've recently started working with JSON in python. Now I'm passing a JSON string to Python(Django) through a post request. Now I want to parse/iterate of that data. But I can't find a elegant way to parse this data, which somehow I'm pretty sure exists.

```
data = request.POST['postformdata']
print data
{"c1r1":"{\"Choice\":\"i1\"}","c2r1":"{\"Bool\":\"i2\"}","c1r2":"{\"Chars\":\"i3\"}"}

jdata = json.loads(data)
print jdata
{u'c1r2': u'{"Chars":"i3"}', u'c1r1': u'{"Choice":"i1"}', u'c2r1': u'{"Bool":"i2"}'}
```

This is what was expected. But now when I want to get the values, I start running into problems. I have to do something like

```
mydecoder = json.JSONDecoder()
for part in mydecoder.decode(data):                                             
    print part
# c1r2 c1r1 c2r1 ,//Was expecting values as well
```

I was hoping to get the value + key, instead of just the key. Now, I have to use the keys to get values using something like

```
print jdata[key]
```

How do I iterate over this data in a simpler fashion, so that I can iterate over key, values?

Comment: You input json doesn't seem to be correct, why c1r1 value is a string `u'{"Choice":"i1"}` instead of dict `{"Choice":"i1"}`

Comment: On Browser side, I'm using JSON.stringify to encode JS objects. Could that be a problem?

Comment: `stringify` should be ok, I use that a lot I think your javascript object itself have the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To iterate key and value, you can write

```
for key, value in jdata.iteritems():
    print key, value
```

You can read the document here: [dict.iteritems](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems)

Answer (score 0):

Just for others to help. In Python3 `dict.iteritems()` has been renamed to `dict.iter()`